# Classic Windows oddities... (NTFS.SYS error that fixes itself?!)

Tags: windows-8, boot, ntfs, bsod

I am getting a boot error with my Windows 8, regarding the fact that my `ntfs.sys` file is corrupt.

However, if I keep retrying the boot through the "Select OS" screen, I boot successfully on the fourth try.

`sfc /scannow` ensures that everything is fine, with no error.

Right before this happened, I had a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT kernel panic, with the following stacktrace:

```
ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+176577 fffff802`ade1e000   fffff802`ae5b4000   0x00796000  0x53fe6f2e  8/27/2014 3:52:14 PM                        
hal.dll                             fffff802`ae5b4000   fffff802`ae624000   0x00070000  0x538bade8  6/1/2014 2:49:12 PM                     
kd.dll                              fffff802`ac949000   fffff802`ac952000   0x00009000  0x5215f8bb  8/22/2013 3:40:43 AM                        
werkernel.sys                       fffff800`172dd000   fffff800`172eb000   0x0000e000  0x5215f8a8  8/22/2013 3:40:24 AM                        
CLFS.SYS                            fffff800`172eb000   fffff800`1734c000   0x00061000  0x53295164  3/19/2014 12:12:20 AM                       
tm.sys                              fffff800`1734c000   fffff800`1736e000   0x00022000  0x5215f875  8/22/2013 3:39:33 AM                        
[ 28 Entries omitted ]
Ntfs.sys                            fffff800`17a6e000   fffff800`17c64000   0x001f6000  0x53d0b61c  7/23/2014 11:30:36 PM
```

What I find odd is that it succeeds, even though the file is supposedly corrupt. So, how would I fix this?

I do not have  a Windows 8 install disk handy, but if it's absolutely necessary, I can get one.

Comment: Have you tried restoring one of the recovery backups usually made before you install windows patches?  Have you tried using windows recovery mode?   Otherwise, your final step would be to start from stratch.

Comment: @mdpc This happened today, I did no updates within the last week. Windows recovery mode (safe mode) throws the same error three times, and then it boots successfully. Reinstalling from scratch is not an option, even though it would probably be the best move as there are many other things wrong with my windows install.

Comment: Try going back to the previous recovery checkpoint.

Comment: @mdpc Is there any other way? I really do not want to have to reconfigure 15+ programs from my last restore point.... But what's weird is that it fails three times and then succeeds. Always.

Comment: Hmmm....I am wondering if you are having a hardware disk issue as well.

Comment: @mdpc Well, I did spill liquid on my computer, but I completely recovered from that. I confirmed that there were no shorts or damages in any way. I'll try running chkdsk. Results show attribute errors. Running `chkdsk /f`

Comment: You need to replace the HDD if you are getting errors.  You cannot detect most damage done by liquids when it comes to electronics.

Comment: @Ramhound Spillproof keyboard. Nothing made it to the mobo. Also, there was no power in the system at all. No CMOS, no AC, no battery. And I am *not* going to buy a new hard drive because of file attribute errors.

Comment: What is likely happening is the file isn't actually corrupt its just located on a bad sector or perhaps a sector that is about to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound Badblocks / SMART / multiple other tests confirm all sectors are good. And, CHKDSK is fixing it as I type.

Comment: You really should be using DISM tool to verify your component store is not corrupt, which is what the SFC tool, uses to verify there isn't anything to repair.  Of course this really does sound like a HDD problem more than a file system problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll do DISM later. I did it not too long ago. Also CHKDSK just reported that it fixed everything. So, FS issue in my mind.

Comment: I never trust chkdisk until it's done one clean pass, after any fixes.

Comment: It might not be the disk, it might be the drive controller. That's the other thing that commonly causes NTFS and disk-related errors. Replace the drive, if the problem doesn't stop then replace the drive controller (most likely part of the motherboard). Alternatively if you think it's a purely software issue, format the disk fully and reinstall Windows on the existing hardware.

Comment: @Tetsujin How about 3 clean passes?